# Delayed CSS3 modal window fade in

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a modal window that I'm trying to have appear after about 7 seconds, with a close button so users can close it if they want to. I got it to close when you click the close button with this code:

```
.tip {
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tip:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="#tip1">Open Modal</a>
<div class="tip" id="tip1">
  Try clicking around a bit.
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
</div>
```

How would I get it to appear automatically when the page first loads after a short delay? I tried using CSS keyframes, but it would disappear a split second after appearing, or the close button wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Put the code in a fiddle or jsbin

Comment: I did that, but for some reason when I was going to post the link, I got a message saying that I should post the code here, rather than just posting a link. I guess I should do both?

Comment: Yes you should do both so that it is helpful of others like me to help you out with your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use animation initial value: (this is longhand)**

> animation-delay: 7s

I've prepared working example for you. I've also used `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, so after animation is finished, opacity remains 1 (not equals 0 as before animation started)

> animation-fill-mode: forwards;

**Putted altogether (shorthand):**

> animation: myFade 0.5s linear 5s;

**Where:**

- `myFade` is **name of your animation**
- `5s` is **delay**
- `0.5s` is **duration of the animation**
- `linear` is **timing-function**

**Below is working example:**

```css
.tip {
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: myFade 0.5s linear 2s ;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  margin:20px 30px;  
}
@-webkit-keyframes myFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.tip:target {  
  display:none;
}

.btn {
  padding: 7px 8px;
  background: #3786ad;
  font-size:12px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  
  
}
```

```html
<p>After 2 seconds popup would appear. Click [X] to close it.</p>
<br />

<a href="#tip1" class="btn">Open Modal</a>
<div class="tip" id="tip1">
  Try clicking around a bit.
  <a href="#tip1" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
</div>
```